# Sum the three first values of a list of tuples and appending the result to it

Tags: python-3.x, sum, tuples

I have a list of tuples in python 3.2 that looks like this:

```
d = [(['dog', '9', 'teacher', '9', 'neighbor', '7'], 'rose   annoyed'), 
(['light', '99', 'lights', '1'], 'jimmy dimmed '),
(['tenant', '66', 'family', '5', 'renter', '5', 'neighbor', '4'], 'aaron evicted '), 
(['world', '8', 'painting', '6', 'website', '4', 'game', '4'], 'ralph created'),
(['zit', '10', 'popcorn', '6', 'pimple', '6', 'cherry', '5'], 'aaron popped')]
```

What I need to do is to sum the three first items of each tuple and append the result to the end of the tuple, so that the outcome would look like:

```
d2 = [(['dog', '9', 'teacher', '9', 'neighbor', '7'], 'rose   annoyed', '25'), 
(['light', '99', 'lights', '1'], 'jimmy dimmed ', '100'),
(['tenant', '66', 'family', '5', 'renter', '5', 'neighbor', '4'], 'aaron evicted ', '76'), 
(['world', '8', 'painting', '6', 'website', '4', 'game', '4'], 'ralph created', '18'), 
(['zit', '10', 'popcorn', '6', 'pimple', '6', 'cherry', '5'], 'aaron popped', '22')]
```

I  tried different ways to `sum` it, but having being nowhere near lucky until now, as I am very new to python. Any suggestions on how this can be accomplished? thank you very much!

Comment: Why do you need to do this? It seems to be a very strange way to organize your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you want:

```
d = [(['dog', '9', 'teacher', '9', 'neighbor', '7'], 'rose   annoyed'), 
(['light', '99', 'lights', '1'], 'jimmy dimmed '),
(['tenant', '66', 'family', '5', 'renter', '5', 'neighbor', '4'], 'aaron evicted '), 
(['world', '8', 'painting', '6', 'website', '4', 'game', '4'], 'ralph created'),
(['zit', '10', 'popcorn', '6', 'pimple', '6', 'cherry', '5'], 'aaron popped')]

d2=[]
for t in d:
    tup=[t[0]]
    tup.append(t[1])
    tup.append(sum(int(x) for x in t[0][1::2]))
    d2.append(tuple(tup))

print(d2)
# [(['dog', '9', 'teacher', '9', 'neighbor', '7'], 'rose   annoyed', 25), 
   (['light', '99', 'lights', '1'], 'jimmy dimmed ', 100), 
   (['tenant', '66', 'family', '5', 'renter', '5', 'neighbor', '4'], 'aaron evicted ', 80), 
   (['world', '8', 'painting', '6', 'website', '4', 'game', '4'], 'ralph created', 22), 
   (['zit', '10', 'popcorn', '6', 'pimple', '6', 'cherry', '5'], 'aaron popped', 27)]
```

If you want to limit to sum the first 3 in the list:

```
d2=[]
for t in d:
    tup=[t[0]]
    tup.append(t[1])
    tup.append(sum(int(x) for x in t[0][1:6:2]))
    d2.append(tuple(tup))

print(d2)
# [(['dog', '9', 'teacher', '9', 'neighbor', '7'], 'rose   annoyed', 25), 
   (['light', '99', 'lights', '1'], 'jimmy dimmed ', 100), 
   (['tenant', '66', 'family', '5', 'renter', '5', 'neighbor', '4'], 'aaron evicted ', 76),
   (['world', '8', 'painting', '6', 'website', '4', 'game', '4'], 'ralph created', 18), 
   (['zit', '10', 'popcorn', '6', 'pimple', '6', 'cherry', '5'], 'aaron popped', 22)]
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you so much! The second solution is exactly what I want!